# ccsprite rotation offset when it rotates to touch location

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, trigonometry

I'm rotating a sprite(`rect`) to face the touch location on the screen. The code works but there is an offset of a couple of degrees that becomes bigger the more vertical the sprite gets. I have added an image below that illustrates my problem very clearly.

The red dot is the touch location that I added in photoshop to show the offset problem. 
So the only sprite that's visible is the the rectangle (IE `rect`).

When I'm at a 90 degree angle the offset is the most apparent. then it gradually disappears again the closer I get to the center.

How can I make it so that the sprite faces the touch location accurately?
Or how can I correct this offset?

```
- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    float angle = atan2f(location.y-rect.position.y, location.x-rect.position.y);
    angle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle);
    angle *=-1;

    rect.rotation = angle;
    float distance = sqrtf(pow((location.x-rect.position.x), 2)+pow(location.y-rect.position.y, 2));
    rect.scaleX = distance;

}
```

[image]

Comment: what is rect? how does it relate to the 2 sprites you show?

Comment: rect is the sprite. the red circle I added in photoshop to show how the touch location relates to the angle of the rect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this statement:

```
float angle = atan2f(location.y-rect.position.y, location.x-rect.position.y);
```

be instead:

```
float angle = atan2f(location.y-rect.position.y, location.x-rect.position.x);
```

?

Furthermore, your issue could be related to your sprite `anchorPoint`.

By default, a sprite's anchor point is `(0.5, 0.5)`, i.e. the very center of the sprite. This is the point that is taken as a reference for your sprite; e.g., you sprite's `position` is the anchor point position; if you apply a rotation angle, your sprite is rotated around the anchor point.

So, you could try and set your sprite anchor point like this:

```
rect.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
```

or

```
rect.anchorPoint = ccp(1,1);
```

and this should go better.

Alternatively, you could leave the anchor point as it is now, but do your math relative to the center of your view (which is a fixed point, I guess):

```
 float angle = atan2f(location.y - viewCenter.y, location.x - viewCenter.x);
```

Comment: aaaargh what a stupid mistake I made. `atan2f(location.y-rect.position.y, location.x-rect.position.x);` was the issue. Code works fine now. Thanks!